# javascript / jquery noob. Many instances of audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just started learning javascript and jquery.
I have made simple audio player that plays short audio clip. 
The problem is that once i click the play button on selected clip, every other clips show stop button, instead of showing the stop button only on clip that is playing.

How do i make that stop button shows only on the clip that is selected?

This is how it works by now:
[www.licktrade.com](http://www.licktrade.com)

Audio file locations will be fetched from mysql database, by now i just made them in html.

The code:

```
echo "<div id='player-grid'>";

echo "<div class='player-wrapper' style='background-image:url(uploads/images/profile_pictures/1.jpg);background-size:100px 100px;'>";
echo "<div class='player'>";
echo "<audio class='audio'><source src='uploads/audio/lick1.mp3'></audio>";
echo "<div class='play'></div>";
echo "<div class='stop'></div>";
echo "</div></div>";

echo "<div class='player-wrapper' style='background-image:url(uploads/images/profile_pictures/1.jpg);background-size:100px 100px;'>";
echo "<div class='player'>";
echo "<audio class='audio'><source src='uploads/audio/lick1.mp3'></audio>";
echo "<div class='play'></div>";
echo "<div class='stop'></div>";
echo "</div></div>";

echo "</div>";

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script>
  $('.stop').hide(); 

    $('.play').click(function() {

      $(this).siblings('.audio').get(0).play();
      $('.play').hide();
      $('.stop').show();
    });

    $('.stop').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings(".audio").get(0).pause();
      $(this).siblings(".audio").get(0).currentTime = 0;
      $('.play').show();
      $('.stop').hide();

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting all instances of `.play` and `.stop`, you just need to select relative to the clicked element. Something like...

```
$('.play').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.audio').get(0).play();
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).siblings('.stop').show();
});

$('.stop').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".audio").get(0).pause();
  $(this).siblings(".audio").get(0).currentTime = 0;
  $(this).siblings('.play').show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Also, you could use jQuery chaining to reduce the amount of times you select `$(this)` - take a look at https://api.jquery.com/end/.

Comment: Thanx, that was fast!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code a bit to only hide & show sibling buttons as you've done for playing the audio. That should do the trick.

```
$('.stop').hide(); 

$('.play').click(function() {

  $(this).siblings('.audio').get(0).play();
  $(this).hide(); //no need to use siblings
  $(this).siblings('.stop').show();
});

$('.stop').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".audio").get(0).pause();
  $(this).siblings(".audio").get(0).currentTime = 0;
  $(this).siblings('.play').show();
  $(this).hide(); //no need to use siblings

});
```

Comment: Thank you! i get it now!

Comment: @exclude1987 no problem :) don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$('.play')` selects all elements with `class="play"` on the **entire page**. When handling a click on a specific play element, you want to hide it and show the stop element next to it. The clicked play element can be accessed via `this`, which you already use to call the `play()` function. Accessing the stop element can be done via [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/), for example.

```
$('.play').hide();
$('.stop').show();
```

becomes

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).next('.stop').show();
```

And similar in the handling of clicks on the stop button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!